# Inconsistent Python Package Installation via Pip Editable

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, pip

I have a python package with the following standard directory structure:

```
package_name/
    setup.py
    package_name/
        module_1.py
        module_2.py
        ...
    tests/
    docs/
```

I've installed this package with `pip3 install -e .`. I've noticed an inconsistent importing issue. (Please read to the end!) If I restart terminal and run the following (1) within the interpreter:

```
>>> from package_name import module_1
```

I get an import error. If I instead run this (2):

```
>>> from package_name.package_name import module_1
```

it imports fine. If I then navigate to the directory and rerun `pip3 install -e .`, I can import in the standard way (following (1)). What on earth is causing this? To make things stranger, I *can* import in the standard way (1) in Jupyter and my IDE without reinstalling the package. This issue only comes up when I open/restart terminal.

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed by adding the main project folder `package_name/` to your `PATH`

Also, try renaming your project folders with different names, in order to avoid confusion for yourself, people working with you and also to help python to find the right module location

You should also create the `__init__.py` files on each module folders, even if those are empty files. This also helps python to find the modules locations.